# Matrices: Write a function in MATLAB that returns all of the positive integer numbers that satisfy the following property

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

Write a function getpythogorean(Z) that returns all of the positive integer numbers that satisfy the following property, for all positive integers less than or equal to Z:

x^2 + y^2 = z^2

The function is not supposed to contain any loops.

Here is a sample input/output

> > getpythogorean(20)
> >
> > ans = [3   4   5; 6   8  10; 5  12  13; 9  12  15; 8  15  17; 12  16  20]

So essentially, you get a value of Z and output the x's, y's, and z's that result in z < 20

As of right now this is what I have:

> function [out] = getpythogorean(Z)
>
> [X,Y] = meshgrid(1:Z,1:Z);
>
> W = sqrt((X.^2)+(Y.^2));
>
> end

Now I need to somehow filter the values of W and save their locations to reference back to the X and Y matrices for the output.  Supposedly this can be done in 4 lines of code.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just add:

```
[x y]=find( abs(W-round(W))<eps )
```

and find the integer values of W and their corresponding x and y indices. Then

```
[x y W(find( abs(W-round(W))<eps ))]
```

will give you all the triplets...